# Global Array in 16 bit C

Tags: c, arrays, global

i am trying to use global char array in my 16 bit kernel by using 2 ways as below :

Way 1

in globals.h

```
char buffer[512];
```

in kernel.c

```
#include "globals.h"
extern char buffer[512];

void func1
{
printf("Address is %X",&buffer[0]);
}
```

in module.c

```
#include "globals.h"
extern char buffer[512];

void func2
{
printf("Address is %X",&buffer[0]);
}
```

here i find both printed memory addresses is different!?

Way 2

in globals.h

```
extern char buffer[512];
```

in kernel.c

```
#include "globals.h"
char buffer[512];

void func1
{
printf("Address is %X",&buffer[0]);
}
```

in module.c

```
#include "globals.h"
char buffer[512];

void func2
{
printf("Address is %X",&buffer[0]);
}
```

here too i find both printed memory addresses is different!?

i was expecting printing the same memory location as it is global array.

can anybody explain this ?

Comment: In both cases you're breaking the "one definition" rule.

Comment: What Paul means is: use `extern` everywhere except in one and only one `.c` file, preferably the one where you declare `extern` in the corresponding `.h` file.

Comment: yep you are right, it works fine now

Comment: There's another design rule saying: never define anything in header files. No variables, no function definitions. If you do, you'll get all kinds of linker errors and oddities, plus it is poor program design. Also, to have one header file full of global variables is very bad design, as it creates a tight coupling between every single file in your project. As a rule of thumb, if you ever find yourself using the `extern` keyword for anything but constants, your program design is poor and needs to be re-made.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In both cases you have definitions of an object `buffer` with external linkage in two translation units.

This is not allowed in C ([ISO/IEC 9899:1999](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), §6.9, 5):

> If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an
>   expression [...], somewhere in the entire program
>   there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier [...]

You are violating this "shall" requirement, hence your program has undefined behavior.

Your compiler seems to create two distinct objects in this case. There is no guarantee, though.

To fix this:

- put an `extern` declaration into the header
- and a definition (without `extern` and/or with initialisation) into either of the C files

Answer (score 1):

Especially in case 2, it is obvious that you have the definition of 2 different arrays, with an external linkage to your .h file - no point in doing this, far from your intention.

Now, in case 1, you are attempting an external linkage on 2 translation units, which will lead to undefined behavior, as `undur_gongor` already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You want to define the array in one .c file:

```
char buffer[512];
```

Then declare it in the .h file:

```
extern char buffer[];
```

Comment: Thanks, I must have been confusing it with functions there.